# Hibernate/HQL - how to get all duplicates returned from database?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

I've got a table containing some duplicates (defined as some specific columns contain the same values). What's the best way to get all those rose back? I need all the duplictes, so ***group by*** in combination with ***having count(*) > 1*** is not the way I'd like to go.

So if my table contains the following data

```
1 - foo - bar - something
2 - foo - bar - another thing
3 - foo - bar - something
4 - foo - bar - something else
```

I'd like to get returned:

```
1 - foo - bar - something
3 - foo - bar - something
```

Thanks a lot for helping!

Stefan

Comment: did you try subselects? did it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Fetch all items (`SELECT * FROM ..`) in a `List`
2. Create a new [`HashBag`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/bag/HashBag.html), passing the list in constructor
3. get only the items where `getCount()` is more than 1.

This will work if you have mapped an object to the table, whose `equals()` method returns `true` if all the properties are the same.

---

Another way is to use a [subselect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries). The subselect being your GROUP BY + COUNT() query, and the outer query comparing with the results of the subquery.

Comment: thanks for formatting my question - and of course thanks for your answer :) Of course I could do it in Java, but I'd like to get only the duplicates back from database...

Comment: why? isn't the end-result important, rather than the means.

Comment: yes - but it's a pretty large table, so it would be nice not to have all the data in the memory.